# Grepping between two strings in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, youtube, grep

I want to grep a string from HTML source, actually a [YouTube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube) link video ID.

Example part of HTML put in to a string variable:

```
$string = 'etc... Your video, <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1InOB234543">video name</a>, etc...';
```

I want only the video link id from entire HTML source.

I tested this in Regex Widget, but I don't know how to put it in Perl:

```
/video, <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=(.*)"/
```

I just want a string between the two word patterns:

```
between 'Your video, <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='
and     '">'
```

Comment: `#include <dont_use_regex_to_parse_html.h>` ;-) .... though in this specific case RegEx is actually a good enough tool if you know what you're doing  - see my comment to the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($string =~ m{video, <a href="http://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=(.*)"}) {
     $video_id = $1;
} else {
     # pattern didn't match
}
```

Notice we used the `{}` delimiters instead of the usual `//` delimiters, since the pattern contains slashes that would otherwise need to be escaped.  Also, the full stops in `www.youtube.com` need to be escaped, since otherwise they are interpreted as wildcards.

Comment: m{} is the same as m// (it's "the m operator", not "the m{} operator").

Comment: This is almost correct but you need to account for the fact that HTML is whitespace invariant and therefore there could be newlines between "," and angle bracket as well as before "href". It night not be likely to occur, but your RegEx better be flexible enough to deal with it

Answer (score 2):

```
my($afterv) = ($text =~ m!video, <a href="http://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=(.*)"!
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses [HTML::LinkExtractor](http://search.cpan.org/~podmaster/HTML-LinkExtractor-0.13/LinkExtractor.pm) from CPAN, so it will work with document containing multiple links:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::LinkExtractor;

my $input = q{etc... Your video, <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1InOB234543">video name</a>, etc...};
my $extractor = HTML::LinkExtractor->new;

$extractor->parse(\$input);

my @ids = map {$_->{href} =~ /watch\?v=(.*)/ }  @{ $extractor->links };
```